# Unicode strings containing unicode characters are always empty

Tags: c, windows, unicode, mingw

I am compiling with  `-municode -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE` flags and using `_tmain` to enable unicode support.

But when I perform operations on any `TCHAR` arrays containing unicode characters, the strings ends up truncated at wherever that character was.

For example:

```
TCHAR buffer[255];
wcscpy(buffer, L"test-");
wcscat(buffer, L"Азәрбајҹан");
/* buffer now contains "test-" */
```

My actual use-case is retrieving a username, which, if it contains special chars, will end up empty wether it's from `GetEnvironmentVariable`, `GetUsername` or even a hardcoded string like above.

EDIT:

Here is a complete minimal reproducible example:

Compiled with `gcc -o error.exe error.c -municode` under:

```
gcc.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.1.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Code:

```
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]) {
    FILE* fp;
    TCHAR buffer[255];

    _tcscpy(buffer, _T("test-"));
    _tcscat(buffer, _T("Азәрбајҹан"));
    _tprintf(_T("Length: %d, Content: %ls\n"), _tcslen(buffer), buffer);

    fp = _tfopen(_T("test.txt"), _T("w"));
    _ftprintf(fp, _T("%ls"), buffer);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

This example prints `15 test-` and puts `test-` into test.txt.

Comment: How do you check?

Comment: I tried wprintf, also the GetEnvironmentVariable and GetUsername functions return the length of the string they got - which is always 0

Comment: From [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/), I see this: `Make sure you are using GCC with the vendor key "w64". To check, use "gcc -dumpmachine". If it reads x86_64-w64-mingw32, you are probably using an old version of gcc that does not support this feature. If it reads x86_64-pc-mingw32, you will need to rebuild your toolchain with the "w64" vendor key to enable the Unicode feature.`

Comment: This is the newest packaged release of mingw64, and it does support -municode

Comment: The compiler flags you list refer to Windows API macros,  they have nothing to do with `wcscpy` or other features mandated by the C Standard

Comment: a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required here

Comment: I do not disagree that OP should edit to provide [mcve], if for nothing else that to show #includes, and signature of `main()` that is used,  But do not understand why the downvote.  OP has been actively involved from the time question became active, and question shows more effort and research then many of the up-voted questions I have seen on this site just today.

Comment: Are your sourcefile saved in utf-8?

Comment: Yes to @stderr, and I have added a Minimal Reproducible Example above.

Comment: I can't get it to work. This TCHAR garbage is not within the C standard. Toss it. Use UTF-8 internally and convert when needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar That's how I do it when I'm unlucky enough, having to write something for Windows. 
If you're gonna allow UTF-8 you won't compile for ANSI anyways so...

Comment: The output clearly shows that `_tcslen(buffer)` is 15, so the problem is not with `_tcscpy(buffer, _T("test-")); _tcscat(buffer, _T("Азәрбајҹан"));`, it has to be with `_tprintf()` and `_ftprintf()` themselves. Why are you using `%ls`? That expects a `wchar_t*` regardless of whether `TCHAR` maps to `char` or `wchar_t`. You should be using `%s` instead, which will expect either `char*` or `wchar_t*` according to what `TCHAR` maps to.

Comment: What is the source file encoding?  `gcc` would probably like it to be UTF-8.  Microsoft assumes an ANSI encoding without the `/utf-8` compiler switch, or using UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding.

Comment: I second the recommendation to avoid `TCHAR`.  It's really not doing you any favors.  You want to use `wchar_t` exclusively on Windows if possible.  If you rely solely on `wchar_t`, then there's no need for conversion.  For a multi-platform application, conversion to/from some common internal format (e.g. UTF-8) tends to be necessary before/after I/O.

Comment: You probably need something like `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);` (for more info, see [_setmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019)) if you're going to rely on `wchar_t` for console output, and the mode parameter of `fopen`/`_wfopen` can be a string like [`"w,ccs=UNICODE"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019#unicode-support).

Answer (score 2):

For wide characters I usually use `wchar_t`.

If that is an option you can use something like:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain() {

#ifdef UNICODE
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
#endif

    wchar_t buffer[255];

    wcscpy(buffer, L"test-");
    wcscat(buffer, L"Азәрбајҹан");
    wprintf(L"%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

With **`VS 2019 with MSVC`** and **`Use Unicode Character Set`** enabled:

[image]

With **`gcc version 9.2.0 (tdm64-1)`**:

[image]

Comment: I am doing precisely this in my environment (using Code::Blocks with GNU GCC compiler and it is outputting exactly what OP shows, i.e. `test-`

Comment: @ryyker, windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows, but different environment. There is some setting that I am not including, but OP is using MinGW.  There is evidently something different between MS setups that works, and ours that does not.

Comment: @ryyker, in VS2019 you can change the settings to Multibyte or Unicode, I use Multibyte, but Unicode also seems to be working. I know you can define this in code but I don't remember how.

Comment: @ryyker "*btw `WCHAR` is just a macro that is defined as `char` for environments that do not have `UNICODE` defined, and `wchar_t` for those that do*" - that is not true at all.  `WCHAR` is always, and always has been, defined as `wchar_t` on all systems. You are thinking of `TCHAR` instead, which indeed does map to either `wchar_t` or `char` based on the presence of, or lack of, the `UNICODE` define.

Comment: @user1456632, no everything looks fine, I added my compilation as an image to the answer. I'm not using mingW though but GCC-TDM64.

Comment: @anastaciu TDM64 is a build of mingw-w64

Comment: @M.M, yes, there may be differences though, I used mingW original build in tthe past and I gave up on it because of some bugs.

Comment: @M.M, I do agree that at this point a minimal reproducible example is the only way to clarify the problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thanks for that correction.  I was doing a lot of reading, and I replaced one for the other in that comment.